# Debugging Error in SQL

Tags: vb.net

Hi guys: Can any one please help me out in this error? Thanks
Error   1   Operator '&' is not defined for types 'String' and 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'.  C:\Users\kathy\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\WindowsApplication1\Form1.vb    20  20  WindowsApplication1

Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
    Public connection As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\kathy\Desktop\generalledger.accdb"
    Public conn As New OleDbConnection

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    conn.ConnectionString = connection
    If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        conn.Open()
        MsgBox("Open")
    Else
        MsgBox("Closed")

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub BtnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnAdd.Click
    Dim sqlQuery As String
    sqlQuery = "insert into voucher(VoucherName, Account_Code, Amount) values ('" & TxtVoucher & "', " & TxtAmount & ", '" & TxtAccount & "')"
    Dim sqlcommand As New OleDbCommand
    With sqlcommand
        .CommandText = sqlQuery
        .Connection = conn
        .ExecuteNonQuery()
    End With
    MsgBox("Save")

End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 1):

Just add **.Text()** in your textboxes.

```
 sqlQuery = "insert into voucher(VoucherName, Account_Code, Amount) values ('" & TxtVoucher & "', " & TxtAmount & ", '" & TxtAccount & "')"
```

To

```
 sqlQuery = "insert into voucher(VoucherName, Account_Code, Amount) values ('" & TxtVoucher.Text() & "', " & TxtAmount.Text() & ", '" & TxtAccount.Text() & "')"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        conn.ConnectionString = connection
        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            conn.Open()
            MsgBox("Open")
        Else
            MsgBox("Closed")

        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnAdd.Click
 conn.Open()
        Dim sqlQuery As String

        sqlQuery = "insert into voucher(VoucherName, Account_Code, Amount) values ('"+ TxtVoucher + "', " + TxtAmount + ", '" + TxtAccount + "')"
        Dim sqlcommand As New OleDbCommand
        With sqlcommand
            .CommandText = sqlQuery
            .Connection = conn
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
 conn.Close()
        End With
        MsgBox("Save")

    End Sub
```